# Is fb:submit gone?

Tags: html, facebook, fbml

I have an old FBML app that uses fb:submit.  When I was trying to make a few changes to it I noticed that the fb:submit buttons aren't functioning and I'm not sure whats happened here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FBML is deprecated, but anything which was already working should still be - if you're sure that this is not a problem on your end there may be a bug with the FBML - if so, please file it at http://bugs.developers.facebook.net

Answer (score -1):

You should absolutely be migrating away from FBML. Facebook has expressed interest in removing it entirely from the Platform by the end of the year.

Opening a bug will likely not be addressed or fixed due to the deprecation of FBML.

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/ ... "We will stop allowing new FBML apps, but will continue to support existing FBML tabs and apps. Instead, we recommend using iframes."

Comment: You're free to do what you like, but Facebook will fully-remove FBML at some point. If you were my client I would recommend you start migration right away.

Comment: True, but there a lot of existing FBML apps out there and we've committed to keeping the old APIs working until such time as we formally deprecate them - if something has broken, it should be fixed

Comment: Ty Igy.  @Mike - This is a huge FBML app that my client doesn't have the budget to migrate, and Facebook hasn't announced they will be removing FBML yet, and I imagine when they do we will have quite some time to move things.